# Java Linter in Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I am trying to switch to Sublime Text 3 and I have run into one problem. When I try to use Java packages to organize my code the linter comes up with an error and I cannot build with the built-in function. Here is the code:

Game.java:

```
package com.tatsu.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3582466025494978079L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game()
    {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        try{
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1)
            {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
            {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick()
    {

    }

    private void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Window.java:

```
package com.tatsu.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 420967586702448927L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }

}
```

It shows errors at the new Window(line 18 of Game.java) and at Game game(line 13 of Window.java). Then it won't build with an error that says:

```
D:\Users\Tyler Miller\Documents\Java\Workspace\Game\src\com\tatsu\main\Game.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game", this);
            ^
  symbol:   class Window
  location: class Game
1 error
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

I imagine it's a classpath error but I don't know how to fix it and I've been searching for forever on google. Help is much appreciated :D

Comment: While I normally promote Sublime to just about everybody, Java is my one exception. Because of the complexity of all the imports, dependencies, multiple source files, build systems, debugging, and whatnot, you would be much better off using an IDE like Eclipse, NetBeans, or IntelliJ. Sublime's Javatar plugin is nice, but it just doesn't cut it compared to the myriad features and assistants in an IDE.

Comment: Yea I figured I would just use sublime for the text editing and then just compile and run from the command line instead of using sublime.

Answer (score 2):

In case others are interested in solving the Sublime-Linter class path problem rather than using Javatar:

The `args` setting in your `SublimeLinter` configuration allows you to pass arguments like the classpath to `javac`.

For example, the following configuration defines the source file encoding,
includes the two libraries `lib/some_lib.jar` and `lib/some_other_lib.jar`
in the classpath,
and defines `src/` as the project's source path:

```
"SublimeLinter": {
    "linters": {
        "javac": {
            "lint": "all",
            "args": [
                "-encoding", "UTF8",
                "-cp", "${project}/lib/some_lib.jar:${project}/lib/some_other_lib.jar",
                "-sourcepath", "${project}/src/"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that options and their values must be separate elements in the array
(i.e. `"args": ["-sourcepath", "/path/to/src"]` does work, while
`"args": ["-sourcepath /path/to/src"]` does not work).

Answer (score 0):

Javatar is a really good alternative. Although there is no real error checking it builds and runs nicely. It also works in pair w/ linter. I'll consider this solved.